# Rename upload file in grocery crud

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I am new in grocery crud, by the by is an incredible extension, congratulations ;)
the question is, I have one form and one field is a type File. I need change the name for the identify object, for example
.
I have the invoice table and one file field, i need when the user save the system should rename the file by id generate plus extension.

If I save the invoice number 18 i need save the file with name 18.pdf.
Thanks in advance.

Note: sorry by my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
$crud->callback_after_insert(array($this, 'rename_img_db'));
public function rename_img_db($post_array,$primary_key){
        //Here goes the get and set querys with your $primary_key
}
```